# Intersection of two localizations is affine domain?

Tags: commutative-algebra

$R = k[x,y,z,w,u]/(xw-z^5 +y^9, y^2u-4x^9-z^2)$, where $k$ is field of characteristic $0$. Then i know that $R$ is not a normal ring, $\dim (R) = 3$.

My question is:

> Is $R_x \cap R_y$ affine?

I tried Macaulay2 but it doesn't localize quotient rings.
Any help would be appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: What is $w$ in the ideal?

Comment: Thank you :)  I forgot to add w. Post edited!

Comment: Did you check if $x,y$ are prime elements in $R$?

Comment: Yes, I checked. (x),(y),(x,y) is not prime in R. But (x,y,z) is a prime ideal of height 1.